# How to break one fat viewModel into multiple smaller ones?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I'm using a fragment to show the user all the details about the Passengers he's added for his trip.
The ViewModel I'm using to do so has many jobs. Like fetching former passengers, adding new passengers if needed, deleting passengers, editing a passenger, etc.
I want to know the best way to break the fat ViewModel into multiple smaller ones.
But keep in mind that separating them is not that simple. Everything is tightly coupled.
For example, all the features I've mentioned above use a list called `existingPassengerList`.

Comment: What language are you using? Java or Kotlin?

Comment: You should clarify what exactly you want. What does the current ViewModel look like? Without code and some more details it will be difficult to help. Generally, you would use the SOLID principles and start refactoring the monolithic class into smaller chunks through Inversion of Control to reduce the tight coupling using Interfaces and Dependency Injection.

Comment: @TheLibrarian I'm using kotlin.

Comment: @ewerspej The current viewModel is around 1000 lines of code responsible for adding, deleting, updating, and editing the passenger list. But the problem is all these functionalities are tightly coupled to the passenger list.

Comment: @MaedeJalali I'm no Kotlin expert, so I wouldn't be able to help with the details, but you should still provide some code so that others can help you. Some sample code that shows the coupling and the problems you are facing when trying to refactor the code. Generally, one approach would be to write unit tests, then start refactoring the monolith step by step and extract the functionality. With Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection the tight coupling can be reduced. There are entire books devoted to this problem (independent of the language): https://stackoverflow.com/a/794554/4308455